# Intuitively understanding the general form of a line through vectors

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry, intuition

Take the general form a line:
$$ax+by+c=0$$
Now if $c=0$, we can view this quite intuitively as the set of vectors $\langle x,y \rangle$ such
$$\langle x,y \rangle\cdot\langle a,b\rangle =0$$
And hence, all the vectors that are perpendicular to $\langle a,b\rangle$.

But what about $c$? How can we incorporate it into this intuitive explanation?

I understand that increasing $c$ will cause the line to move along the vector $\langle a,b\rangle$ (away from the point $(a,b)$), but what is a good way to understand this.

The two starting points I've come up with are:

- We can think of it instead as the set of all vectors $\langle x,y,0 \rangle$ that are orthogonal to $\langle a,b,c\rangle$, though, without seeing this visualised I'm having trouble picturing this.
- We can think of it as the scalar product of $\langle a,b \rangle$ and $\langle x,y\rangle$ being equal to $-c$. So far this still isn't really helping me though. It isn't really easy to visualise.

Comment: What about the projective geometry view: a homogeneous $ax+by+cz=0,$ which has an explanation as a plane through the origin with a normal vector, where you recover the affine line $ax+by+c=0$ in the $x,y$-plane when intersecting with the screen $z=1.$

Comment: I corrected the starting equation: suppose that is what you meant,

Comment: Use `\langle` and `\rangle` instead of `<` and `>` for vector brackets.

Comment: Hint: Consider the orthogonal projections of points on the line onto $\langle a,b\rangle$. Do they have anything in common?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: line_dot_prod_1]

We have
$$
\eqalign{
  & \Delta {\bf P} \cdot {\bf n} = 0\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad \left( {{\bf P} - {\bf P}_{\,0} } \right) \cdot {\bf n} = 0\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad {\bf P} \cdot {\bf n} = {\bf P}_{\,0}  \cdot {\bf n}\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad ax + by = c \cr} 
$$
so that
$$
c = {\bf P}_{\,0}  \cdot {\bf n}
$$
is a sort of measure of the (signed) distance of the line from the origin.

If $b \ne 0$, we can divide through by it
$$
y =  - {a \over b}x + {c \over b}
$$
and get that $c$ is proportional to the $y$ intercept.
otherwise we can divide by $a$ and "measure" the distance by the $x$ intercept.

And if you are in the Euclidean plane, then we can put
$$
{a \over {\sqrt {a^{\,2}  + b^{\,2} } }}x + {b \over {\sqrt {a^{\,2}  + b^{\,2} } }}y = {c \over {\sqrt {a^{\,2}  + b^{\,2} } }}
$$
and
$$
{c \over {\sqrt {a^{\,2}  + b^{\,2} } }}
$$
is actually the distance of the line from the origin.

*---  note  ---*

Answering to your comment, ${\bf P}_{\,0}$ can be any point on the line, so in particular it can correspond to $H$.
In any case it is
$$
{\bf P}_{\,0}  \cdot {\bf n} = {\bf H} \cdot {\bf n} = c
$$

Note that if you are working in the [affine space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space) we cannot talk
of "distance" in the same acception as in the Euclidean space.

And in the Euclidean space, to have that $c$ be the  distance of the line from the origin, signed along the direction of 
${\bf n}$ you shall first normalize ${\bf n}$.

Comment: Can we let ${\bf P_0}$ be in the same direction as ${\bf n}$ so that $c$ is just the magnitude of the vector ${\bf n}$ multiplied by the signed distance to the line from the origin?

Comment: @PolymorphismPrince: added a note in my answer